# caching by inbound url not working because of timestamp querystrings

Tags: servicestack

My web guys are appending a timestamp to the end of their service calls to help overcome local javascript caching. So a typical querystring for a service call ends like this.

```
../LvGmReferencePeriods?Dt=2018-04-06&_=1532616150685
```

where everything after &_ is the timestamp. This is defeating the CacheResponse[] based caching, which works off the url, because every call to the same service now has a different url.

I was wondering if I could strip off the timestamp off all inbound service calls, perhaps using a GlobalRequestFilter, but I was unsure which properties I would have to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See at [Advanced CacheInfo Customization](http://docs.servicestack.net/cacheresponse-attribute#advanced-cacheinfo-customization) for details on how the `[CacheResponse]` attribute works where it populates a [CacheInfo](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/CacheInfo.cs) object in `IRequest.Items[Keywords.CacheInfo]` which you can access in your Request Filters and Services to modify the `KeyBase` property used for the cache key which by default uses the incoming `Request.RawUrl`.